# jQuery Easing Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-animations, jquery-easing

I need to show an animation where an input box falls from top, expands after falling and user can type in some text in that box using jQuery easing.. same effect like https://www.meperdi.es/

Comment: I have tried jQuery Easing plugin since I was bit hesitant to use only CSS for the animation as some users might not have new age browsers. But will use wick3d's solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some `CSS` and some `jQuery` addclass may help?
https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/s4L1909p/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the animation you posted as an example, you can animate the input **without** using jQuery.

In fact - never use jQuery for animations, as it's very inefficient.

Still - animating the input can be done like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpbya9q2/6/)

```
input.anim{
  display:block;
  margin:3rem auto;
  animation: showExtend 1.2s cubic-bezier(.25,1.52,.59,.9) forwards;
}


@keyframes showExtend{
  from{
    transform: translate(0%, -5000%) rotate(35deg) scale(1,.1);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translate(0%, 15%) rotate(15deg) scale(1,.5);
  }
  to{
    transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0deg) scale(1,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks wick3d. It was really helpful. You deserve +1 :)

Comment: My pleasure ;] If you find my answer helpful - mark it down as the solution. Only tou can do it ;) Also, feel free to +1 my answear if it helped.